# How to modify existing excel file using PHP?

Tags: php, excel, pear

I have a excel i need to add some more sheets into the excel using PHP, i have used PEAR, there i tried only can write excel and read a file, not able to read and modify the file, guys can you help me in this?

Thanks in advance

Prabu

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You will need 2 pear packages

1. PHP-ExcelReader package
2. Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package

What you need to do is read first the excel file use **PHP-ExcelReader package**
It reads the binary format of XLS files directly and can return values and formats from any cell. 
http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

read the excel file

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls");
```

show the data of the file

```
$data->dump($row_numbers=false,$col_letters=false,$sheet=0,$table_class='excel')
```

---

Once you have stored the data in a variable save the data in another file this time you will use the **The Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer package**
https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer

```
 <?php
require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';
$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer('test.xls');
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('My first worksheet');
if (PEAR::isError($worksheet)) {
    die($worksheet->getMessage());
}
$workbook->close();
?>
```

Comment: http://pear.php.net/ doesn't work at the moment, script available on  https://github.com/pear/Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer