# Getting database data into existing Excel document tab

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

I have a script that grabs data from a MySQL database table and creates a new .csv excel document and inserts all the data there. Now note that this scripts CREATES a NEW csv file.

Part of the script:

```
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM ".$table."");
$i = 0;
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if($row['Field'] != 'id'){
            $csv_output .= $row['Field']."; ";
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
$csv_output .= "\n";

$values = mysql_query("SELECT title, firstname, initials, lastname, address, address_nr, emailaddress, zipcode, city, phone, mobile, website FROM ".$table." WHERE addressbook = '$addressbook_id'");
while ($rowr = mysql_fetch_row($values)) {
    for ($j=0;$j<$i;$j++) {
        $csv_output .= $rowr[$j]."; ";
    }
    $csv_output .= "\n";
}

$filename = $file."_".date("Y-m-d_H-i",time());
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-disposition: csv" . date("Y-m-d") . ".csv");
header("Content-disposition: filename=".$filename.".csv");
print $csv_output;
exit;
```

Now comes the problem. A company that needs this data, already has made a .xlsx Excel file containing invisible columns that they need, plus the columns already have different names and the file has two different tabs. One with text and one where the data should come in to.

Problem 1: if I upload this file to my webserver, how can I make the script use this file instead of creating a new one?

Problem 2: How can it be saved as .xlsx file in stead of .csv?

Problem 3: There are 2 tabs in the sheet. How can the data get inserted into the 2nd tab named "2. data"?

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look to this post: [How to modify existing excel file using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144638/how-to-modify-existing-excel-file-using-php)

I hope with the information there you can solve your problem.

You will need some Pear packets to PHP.

Comment: Thank you, I've seen that post before. Problem is that my webhost does not have these packets installed, plus they refuse to do so.

Comment: Install Pear is not a really challenger task so I suggest you to insist with your hosting service (Almost all have pear installed), or you also could install a local server for this task. Or at worst watch the code of those package and create your own script. Remember that Pear is a collect of "well doing" scripts for common problems.

Comment: This link could help you with the setup: http://www.geeksengine.com/article/install-pear-on-shared-web-host.html

Comment: Thanks. I have looked into it and my webhost allows me to install PEAR, so that is solved. I am going to call the company in a half hour to see if there's an alternative solution because I am a newbie when it comes to modifing Excel documents and it's also where my PHP knowledge ends.

Comment: I'm glad the information has been helpful. Use those PEAR Packages is not very difficult but need some time to read the manual and do the implementation: http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.intro.php Best wishes.