# Converting a txt file to excel,then modiying excel and import the new excel file to a database

Tags: php, database, excel, file

I would like to convert a txt file to excel and then modify certain data inside the excel file and then import this new excel file to a database using PHP. The contents of the excel file, for example, will be with products and prices of them and the modification will be on the prices.

Is this even possible using PHP or I will need something else?

Comment: Do you need to store the data in a excel file in addition to the database, or could that be bypassed?

Comment: It's certainly possible, have you tried looking? - http://www.phpexcel.net might be a starting point

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144638/how-to-modify-existing-excel-file-using-php?

Comment: csv is always better than a proprietary format.

Comment: :@ John Kane Well the data that is inside the excel file will be imported to the database not the file itself.So i think i should store the data of the excel and then put them to the database.

Comment: :@ Makr Baker Yes I found phpexcel too just wanted to be sure that I can do it with this and php

Comment: @Kostis What I meant was that, that if you did not need to use a csv file as an intermediary step it and a record could be kept in memory before just writing it to a database, it might be worth just doing that.

Comment: csv is sometimes better than a proprietary format, unless you want to use special features of that proprietary format... such as formatting, data tools, formula evaluation, etc

Comment: Anything is better than proprietary, until you ask end users to modify raw data without a tool - just sayin...

Answer (score 2):

Seems like a rather roundabout way of doing this, but I've had great success with Excel/php with [phpExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).  That will get read/write Excel, but putting it into the database will likely require som php coding.

Comment: Yes I found this phpExcel myself too but I wanted to be sure that it is possible with this :) THanks!

Comment: I open/read/modify/write spreadsheets all day long with it quite efficiently, good luck - I hope you accept this answer then :)

Answer (score 2):

If you're just editing datas in Excell (no formulas ...) you should try csv format  ...
  I think that you should send a example of your txt file ...

Mimiz

Comment: +1 for suggesting csv only if additonal features of excel not required