# How can i Insert a row in Excel File with PHP?

Tags: php, excel, insert, excel-2007, xlsx

i'm new with php, maybe this is can be stupid..
I have 5 parameters to add in Excel 2007 file (*.xlsx) name, phone, email and adress.

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone  = $_POST['phone'];
$adress = $_POST['adress'];
```

how can i add 1 row each time the code run.

Comment: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify existing excel file using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144638/how-to-modify-existing-excel-file-using-php)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/) you would do this to write a single row:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = 1;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $_POST['name']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('B'.$row, $_POST['email']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('C'.$row, $_POST['phone']);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('D'.$row, $_POST['adress']);
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('myfile.xlsx');
```

Reading files involves starting here and working forward:

```
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$data = $objReader->load('myfile.xlsx');
$objWorksheet = $data->getActiveSheet();
```

Obviously you'll need to do more digging into the docs to learn how to open existing files and append to them, but that hopefully gives you a kick in the right direction.

Comment: yeah, i'm using PHPExcel, but this code, i've already tried.

$LastRow = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
$row = $LastRow + 1;
       
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A'.$row, $_POST['name'])

the only problem is, it always create a new xls rather than add...
any ideia ?

Comment: When you save, save with the same filename as you loaded. Then it won't create a new Excel file, but will overwrite the original

Comment: @user1818079, it will help if you update your answer above to post the exact code you have so far.