# Using php to pull a keyword from a text file and put into a specific table cell

Tags: php, html, html-table, fopen

below is my html page using php fopen to pull a text file and output to two columns.  I need to go further with this and pull "specific keywords" from the text file and put in a "specific" row cell.  Lets say keyword "red" needs to go to cell row 1 and "blue" to cell row 2, etc, etc.

I know there are two table columns in this html to deal with but if someone can assist on just one column, I can figure out the 2nd column.

Maybe there is a better way of doing this than php would be great as well.

```
    <head>
    <title>Snapshots and Backups</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2 style="font-family:tahoma;">Below are Nightly Snapshots & Tape Backups</h2>

    <h3 style="font-family:tahoma;">

    <p style="color:green; font-weight:bold">

    <table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" height="30" width="100%">
    <thead>
            <tr>
                    <th scope="col">

    <b>Nightly Snapshots</><br>
    <?php

    $f = fopen("./backups/serversnaps.txt", "r");

    // Read line by line until end of file
    while(!feof($f)) {
        echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
    }

    fclose($f);

    ?>

    </th>

    <th scope="col">

   <b>Tape Backups</b>

    <?php

    $f = fopen("./backups/servertape.txt", "r");

    // Read line by line until end of file
    while(!feof($f)) {
        echo fgets($f) . "<br />";
    }

    fclose($f);

    ?>

    </th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    </p>

    </h3>

    <h2 style="font-family:tahoma;">This is the End of File</h2>

    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please Improve your Language. Nothing is Clear!

Comment: You already have the contents of the file in the $f variable. Parse through that variable and pick out the keywords you need and then use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979226/how-can-i-insert-a-row-in-excel-file-with-php to insert the data into excel.

Comment: Thanks for that McCormick.  So your saying to use phpexcel and let it write out and excel file then view that using html?  Sorry for my noob language but it's been awhile since I dabbed into coding.

Comment: Textfile would look like this:

<code>red here is some data

blue here is some more data</code>

Now the code would pick up the keyword "red" and put that whole line in a specific table row.  Keyword "blue would go into another table row.  And so forth.

Ugh, can't make the textfile with rows in this comment.

Comment: Can anyone offer more suggestions please?